# How to trigger pronounciation when using word look up?

Tags: dictionary, look-up

When I do a deep track pad press on an English word, a pop up box will be displayed to show me the word's definition.

But I also want to hear the word's pronunciation.

How can I do that?

Here's a sample image of what the look up looks like:

[image: A sample image of what look up looks like]